# Integration by Parts in derivation of LSZ formula

Tags: quantum-field-theory

I am working out Mark Srednicki's QFT. I shall be grateful if someone could explicitly give me the integration by parts of the fifth line of equation (5.10) on page 36 of Srednicki's book. How do we move the Laplacian on to the field Phi(x). I always get an extra term so could someone kindly work it out for me?

Comment: You mean you get a boundary term? Usually in these calculations we assume everything goes to zero at infinity.

Comment: Not the boundary term.  Could you kindly show the calculation?

Comment: @Raul781 how about the other way around? would you mind showing your math so others can help you spot the mistake?

Comment: Please show exactly which equations you mean, as well as what you've tried. Questions should be self-contained, and should show clear effort towards solving the problem.